# Does Being Buried next to Christians Affect the Soul of a Ben/Bat Noach?

Tags: gentiles, funeral-burial-levaya, noahidism

I asked this question once and never got an answer and part of it is because historically the only reasons why Gentiles approached the Jewish community was either to convert them or for blood libels. Question: Does it affects the Soul in the afterlife and/or makes a difference at all to be buried among Xtians when you're a Ben/Bat Noach since there would be ritual ceremonies for others next to the Ben/Bat Noach's gravesite?

Comment: You're worried that a pagan ritual happening near someone's grave, long after they're dead and buried, which the deceased had zero interest in while alive, will mess with their soul in the afterlife? I don't hear it. (Not saying Christians are pagans, just working from an extreme example.)

Comment: A more interesting question is that as a matter of policy we don't bury Jews next to non-Jews, or theoretically even righteous Jews next to sinners. Would that apply to Noahides next to non-Noahides? Ask a rabbi who specializes in Noahidism. If I'm not mistaken with regards to the Jew/non-Jew or righteous/sinner, Rabbi Feinstein writes: "just bury them in the right place now -- get margins of 16 feet from the problematic existing grave -- and if someone later buries in the spot in between, that's not your concern." (So it's about "how to do a burial" now, not "it will ruin the soul later.")

Comment: There was a Jewish family heavily pressuring the rabbi to allow a non-Jewish relative to be buried with them; Rabbi Feinstein said if the rabbi can get them to bury with 16-foot margins now, good enough and don't go to war. So I'd imagine if there are strong family pressures for a Noahide to be buried in a family plot, similar considerations would apply. This is assuming the family plot is at a generic cemetery, e.g. "Springfield Memorial Gardens." I'd imagine that burial on the grounds of a church could be seen as a declaration that the deceased identified with the church.

Comment: See Sanhedrin 46b